# Why Was My Question Put On Hold

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed

My question [What Is The Most Efficient Way To Organize A Lot Of Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414591/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-organize-a-lot-of-methods) was put on hold for being "primarily opinion-based." I don't see how asking about efficiency is primarily opinion-based. Would someone tell me specifically what is opinion based about it. I did find an answer, through more of my own research, but I can't post it, because of it being on hold.

Comment: I don't think its clear you are talking about Runtime Performance. It looks like you asking for the more subjective how do I organize a bunch of methods into a bunch of files which really has nothing to do with efficiency.

Comment: @FDinoff Thanks I will clarify

Comment: +1 for asking constructively about this here.

Comment: I still think it's entirely opinion-based since there is no hard data, and based on the discussion that has ensued, I'd say there are grounds for closing it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think its clear that you are talking about Runtime Performance. It looks like you are asking for the more subjective how do I organize a bunch of methods into a bunch of files which really has nothing to do with efficiency.

Comment: Have I changed it to make it obvious? I mean you understood what I meant.

Comment: Yeah It looks fine. I was just moving the comment into an answer.